# What is the relationship between recursion and proof by induction?

Tags: recursion, type-theory, induction

What is the relationship between recursion and proof by induction?

Let's say `fn(n)`,

recursion is `fn(n)` calls itself until meet `base condition`;

induction is when `base condition` is meet, try to prove `(base case + 1)` is also correct.

It seems recursion and induction are in different direction. One starts from `n` to `base case`, the other is start from `base case` to `infinite`.

Could someone explain the idea in details?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recursion and induction are very much the same thing! This becomes obvious if you use a programming language with dependent types, such as Agda, but it can be demonstrated to some extent without them too.

Remember, that due to the [Curry-Howard correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), types are propositions and programs are proofs. When you are writing a function of type `Nat -> Nat` (I will use Haskell notation), you are trying to prove that, given a natural number, your program will terminate and produce another natural number. Now we may have a definition like this:

```
f 0 = 1
f (1 + n) = n * f n
```

which is both a recursive definition of `f` and an inductive proof of its termination at the same time!

You can read it as a proof in a following way:

Let's prove that f x terminates for any x.

- Base case: we have `f 0` constant by definition so it terminates.
- Inductive case: if we assume `f n` termiates, `f (1 + n)` terminates too (because all the functions it calls terminate).

Note that as recursion is not limited to a function decrementing its counter, induction is not limited to natural numbers either. There is also structural induction, corresponding to structural recursion, both of which are very popular in mathematics/programming. These are to be used when trying to prove things/define functions on more complex data structures (lists/trees/etc.).

Now, to address your concern about the "direction" of the recursion/induction. It is helpful to consider "direction of demand" and "direction of supply" here, which are opposite.

When you define recursive function, the demand (method calls) flows from larger values to base case. On the other hand, the supply (the return values) flow from the base case to the larger values of parameter. "definedness" is another way way of thinking about supply. It starts at the base case and propagates to infinity via the recursive case.

Now, when you are doing inductive proofs, theorems are your supply while goals are your demand. You can make a theorem T 0 out of the base case and then improve to however large T n you like using inductive case: your supply flows from 0 to infinity. Now if you have a goal G n, you can make a smaller goals G (n-k) out of it using the inductive step until you reach zero. This way your demand goes from n to 0.

As you can see, the direction of supply is "to infinity" in both cases and the direction  of demand is "to zero" in both cases.

You can also reverse the apparent order in the descriptions of induction and recursion without changing their meaning:

Induction is when to prove that P n holds you need to first reduce your goal to P 0 by repeatedly applying the inductive case and then prove the resulting goal using the base case.

Similarly, recursion is when you first define a base case and then define the further values in terms of the previous ones. See, the directions are easily swapped!

Comment: I disagree with this strongly, particularly your notion that direction is not a valid thing to consider. You cannot simply turn it around if only for the reason that the natural numbers are bounded below but not bounded above. I am not familiar with structural induction and I think there is a distinction being made here between this and mathematical induction as a form of proof. That said, as your answer has been accepted by the OP it is clear that your description satisfies him and that ultimately is the purpose of this site so I shall delete my answer.

Comment: @mathematician1975, I don't think the purpose of this site is the OP satisfaction. We should strive to find the truth by pointing out each other's mistakes. Now about the direction reversal. I have provided examples of sentences with directions reversed. Are the sentences wrong? I think they are still true. Both induction and recursion are about formation of *finite* chains of reasoning/method calls. I don't see anything wrong in reversal of finite chains, do you?

Comment: I've tried to clarify my point by introducing the "direction of supply/demand" notion. Not sure if it makes much sense, but there you go. :D

Comment: @Rostor I agree with what you say here "I don't think the purpose of this site is the OP satisfaction.". I simply do not see mathematical induction as a finite process, nor recursion for that matter (unless purely in the context of computer programming). I see induction as a means of establishing proof of some statement that holds for all natural numbers. This very notion implies that the process is not finite since the set of natural numbers is not finite. Consider the sum of natural numbers from 1 to N. Induction give a proff, while induction merely an alternative means to calculate the sum.

Comment: I guess we will not convince one another anyway - but it is good to debate these things regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Sequence

You Start with a Sequence.

You identify a pattern that seems to hold true for every term in the Sequence.

Make use of Mathematical Induction to prove that the pattern holds true for every term down the Sequence.

#### Method of Proof by Mathematical Induction

```
- Step 1. Basis Step.
    Show that P(a) is true. Pattern that seems to hold true from a.

- Step 2. Inductive Step
    For every integer k >= a
        If P(k) is true then P(k+1) is true.
            To perform this Inductive step you make the Inductive Hypothesis. (P(k) is true)
            Supposition: that P(k) is true, where k is any particular, but arbitrarily chosen integer with k >= a.
            Inductive Hypothesis is the supposition that P(k) is true
        Show that P(k + 1) is true
            Notice: a, a+1, a+2, a+3, ... k, k+1
                        for every integer k >= a, that p(k) is true
```

#### Recursion

```
Start with Sequence: Each term has a recurrence relation with the previous term.

A recurrence relation is an equation that defines each later terms of a Sequence by reference to earlier terms in the Sequence
        Now you have a Sequence at hand and for defining the nth term of the Sequence you refer (nth - 1), (nth -2) ...
Initial Condition
    An Initial Term that is defined (returns a value)
        As previously mentioned for defining the nth term of the Sequence you refer (nth - 1), (nth -2) ... an so forth until reaching the initial term that starts solving the problem for defining the nth term of the Sequence
            Notice: n, n-1, n-2, n-3, ... Initial Term
```

#### Recursive Specification

```
Recursive Relation
Initial Values
```

#### Combine

```
- Sequence.
- Recursive Specification: Recurrence Ralation & Initial Condition.
- Explicit Formula: Solution to the Recurrence Ralation.
- Correctedness of the formula proven by Mathematical Induction.
```

#### Recursive Leap of Faith

The most difficult part of solving problems recursively is to figure out how knowing the solution to the smaller problems of the same type as the orignal problem will give you a solution to the problem as a whole.

You suppose you knwo the solutions to the smaller subproblems, the supposition that the smaller subproblems have already been solved has been called the Recursive Leap of Faith.

The Recursive Leap of Faith is similar to the inductive hypothesis in a proof by mathematical induction.

#### Relationship between Mathematical Induction & Recursion?

- Sequence

  - Think in terms of the following:

    ```
     Sequence, Pattern & Terms.

     Both Mathematical Induction & Recursion deal with these.
    ```
- Direction

  - Mathematical Induction

    ```
     `a, (a+1), (a+2), (a+3), ... k, (k+1)`

     Start from base term `a` and prove that for `k >= a`, every subsequent `k + 1` is true
    ```
  - Recursion

    ```
     `k, (k-1), (k-2), (k-3), ... a`

     Define the `kth term`.
     `k` refers to earlier terms in the sequence `(k-1)`, `(k-2)` preceding and so forth arriving at the initlal term `a`
    ```
- Supposition

  - Both Inductive Hypothesis & Recursive Leap of Faith deal with a Supposition; a Hypothesis.

    ```
    Mathematical Induction: Inductive Hypothesis is the supposition that P(k) is true; where k is any particular, but arbitrarily chosen integer with k >= a.
    Recursion: Recursive Leap of Faith is the supposition that the smaller subproblems have already been solved.
    ```
- Correctedness of the Explicit Formula proven by Mathematical Induction

  You use mathematical induction to check the correctness of your formula

##### Reference

[Discrete Mathematics with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1337694193)